# How to pick the right images for an object detection model for only 1 tag?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, training-data

UseCase: I'm trying to extract certain parts of a screenshot which is taken from a game (with a tf object detection model) and extract the text within this part (custom model for the font used in the game).

I have trained a custom model based on SSD Mobilenet V2 and the object detection works quite okish, but sometimes the bounding box is off. I googled about selecting the right images and the right amount for training the custom model, but I couldn't find a good hint in the right direction.

I try to extract the following (surrounded by red):
[image: Extraction]

The environmen can change:

- Resolution of the game can be different (1920x1080, WHQD etc.)
- Text in the box is not always the same

I have trained with 120 self made images (1920x1080) (90% for training 10% for test) (all of these images where a screenshot of the game) and as I mentioned the results are okish. Sometimes the detected area is off (cutting the content of the box or including a lot area of the box surroundings).

Maybe someone can help me/answering the following questions:

1. Could a bigger training dataset increase the accuracy?
2. Should I also take different resolutions into account when creating the training data?
3. Would it make sense to feed only the boxes without the rest of the game screenshot into the training? Or should I mix screenshots of the whole game and only box screenshots?
   [image: Box only]

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: 1) Yes, 120 images is very small dataset for image recognition
2) Your network always get image with same resolution, so no. You only need to provide, that images will be resize to needed resolution before recognition.

Comment: If this box with text is in same place on screen, maybe calculate it's position and crop screen will be better solution? Also you can look simple CV methods, like contours/borders detection etc. (For example, this methods are applied in number plates recognition, where also need recognize rectangle with text)

Comment: 1) I will increase the dataset for the next training round
2) So if I get you right I could just downscale higher resolutions to my trained data (1920x1080) ? (I won't support lower resolutions than 1920x1080) ?
3) It is not always on the same place. So calculation is not really possible (the boxes also differ in size). I thought about doing some processing with countours - maybe I give that also a try and see how good it works :). Thanks for your input!

Comment: What model are you using? Maybe it doesn't get 1920x1080 images and actually works with smaller resolution? Maybe your framework automatically resizes the training data (or it's implemented in the training scripts)

Comment: As @Elmir mentioned, probably input images are resized to e.g. 400x400 - and it's not a problem, because the task does not seem to be difficult. Make sure that your training data contains pictures with text in different places, text boxes of different sizes - in other words good representation of your use case. In this instance it will be working great!

Comment: Hi @user2450489 will the text always be inside the red box ? And will the text always be the same or different?